# tslint issue with angular - All imports are unused

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, tslint

I am doing some refactoring with my application and resolving issues raised by ts lint.

I was able to resolve most of the issues but the following two issues  remains unresolved.

**`ERROR:`**

```
view.component.ts[1, 61]: 'OnInit' is declared but never used.
done.component.ts[3, 1]: All imports are unused.
```

if you really look at the code of both the components,

**view.component.ts**

```
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit  {

ngOnInit(): void {
    const ticketId = 123;
}
```

It has been actually used.

while the 2nd one shows,

**done.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseComponent } from '../../../base.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'done',
    templateUrl: 'done.component.html'
})

export class DoneComponent extends BaseComponent {
}
```

here is the **[`ts-lint`](https://gist.github.com/sajeetharan/c3900404fb4bcf70a6650df6b58494eb)** config.

both imports have been used. Similarly it shows many angular methods as not used. is this a common issue with tslint? if not how can this be resolved?

Comment: is all of your latest changes with`view.component.ts` and `done.component.ts` are actually saved on disk?

Comment: @Kuncevic yes i event did npm cache clean

Comment: Do you have tslint.json? if yes will you please also post that ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi https://gist.github.com/sajeetharan/c3900404fb4bcf70a6650df6b58494eb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is because of `no-unused-variable` try to ( remove it / make it `false` ) and recompile your code:

Change :

```
no-unused-variable : true,
```

To :

```
no-unused-variable : false,
```

> Disallows unused imports, variables, functions and private class
>   members. Similar to tsc’s –noUnusedParameters and –noUnusedLocals
>   options, but does not interrupt code compilation.

For More Detail Please Go Through The Link : https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/1481

Comment: why should i make it false?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, it the property that causing the issue , you can read more about it , https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/1481

Comment: @Sajeetharan, Done :)

Comment: This is currently deprecated, but there's talk of un-deprecating it. https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4100